# Value of prediction of GLM in r

Tags: r

My data include: Year (2000-2010), Quarter (Q1-Q4), Area (A1-A5), Effort (number of hooks), Catch (number of fish).
I used GLM to predict the catch value.
Here is my code:

```
 `model = glm( log(catch) ~ Year + Quarter + Area + log(Effort), data = 
  data, family = gussian())`
```

And I want to get the value of prediction 
at all conditions in Quarter 3 and per 1000hooks!
so i wrote:

```
`X0 = model.martrix(model)
 effort.pred=1000
 X0[,”log(Effort)”] <- log(effort.pred)
 X0[,”QuarterQ2”] <- 0
 X0[,”QuarterQ3”] <- 1
 X0[,”QuarterQ4”] <- 0
 X0[,”AreaA2”] <- 1
 X0[,”AreaA3”] <- 1
 X0[,”AreaA4”] <- 1
 X0[,”AreaA5”] <- 1
 pred = X0%*%martrix(coef(model))`
```

But, I can’t get the value…
I just wanna get the table

```
 Year    Quarter    Area     pred
 2000      Q3        A1        ?
 2000      Q3        A2        ?
 2000      Q3        A3        ?
 2000      Q3        A4        ?
 2000      Q3        A5        ?
 2001      Q3        A1        ?
                .
                .
                .
                .
 2010      Q3        A3        ?
 2010      Q3        A4        ?
 2010      Q3        A5        ?
```

Could anybody help me, please!!!!

Comment: I recommend using the `predict()` function with `type = "response"` (see the documentation for `?predict.glm` for details, like the `newdata` argument).

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson! ... using parentheses inside column names is extremely unwise. You also misspledled "gaussian".

Comment: I do not know the data set, but the number of fish `catch` is count data. I think poisson regression might be reasonable. You did log transformation, but it does not fit _poisson random component_. `catch ~ Year + Quarter + Area + log(Effort)` formula and `poisson(link = "log")` family is possible.